# Creating a custom data structure in Java and want to add elements to the end of the list rather than the start

Tags: java, generics, structure

The title basically explains the issue I want to solve. Right now I'm adding elements to my list, but they're being added to the start of the list rather than the end, and I want to add them onto the end but I can't figure out how right now. Here's how my two classes look (the element/linkedlist):

**List element:**

```
public class ListElement<E> {

public ListElement<E> next;
public E data;

public ListElement(E data) {
    next = null;
    this.data = data;

    }
}
```

**Adding to the list using element:**

```
public class OptimizedLog<E> implements Iterator<E> {
public ListElement<E> list;

public OptimizedLog() {
    list = null;
}


public void add(E data) {
    ListElement<E> le = new ListElement<E> (data);
    le.next = list; // next becomes null
    list = le; // list becomes le
}
```

Anybody got any advice?

Comment: Unrelated, but your comments in “add” seem wrong (next doesn’t become null, it becomes list) then redundant (that’s what assignment does—no need to comment that). In any case—you’re explicitly setting the first element in list to the new item. If you want to add it to the end then go to the end first and set the “next” of the last item to the new item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public void addFirst(E data) {
    ListElement<E> le = new ListElement<E>(data);
    le.next = list; 
    list = le; 
}

public void addLast(E data) {
    if (list == null) {
        addFirst(data);
        return;
    }
    ListElement<E> current = list;
    while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }

    ListElement<E> le = new ListElement<E>(data);
    current.next = le;
}
```

But why you don't use standard java data structures for that task?

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to point them in the right direction rather than doing their assignment for them?

Comment: Yes, it would. Missed the word "classes" in the question. On the other hand, my answer is definitely not production ready solution for deque, so it can be considered as pointing to right direction.

Comment: This is a homework assignment, not production code. You did his homework.